# Extract words from specific words until next punctuation mark [Python Regex]

Tags: python, regex

I'm really new to programming and I'm struggling with some regex code.

What I want to do is extracting words from some specific words until the next punctuation mark (`.` `,` `?` `!`)
I already managed to capture the words after my specific words, but by taking the next 6 words.

Btw my code is in Python, here it is:

```
words_to_find = r"(?<=ou est )\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*|" \
        r"(?<=ou se trouve )\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*|" \
        r"(?<=ou se situe )\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*"
found_words = re.findall(words_to_find, sentence, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

As you can see, my way to capture the words isn't really beautiful. "ou est", "ou se trouve" and "ou se situe" are my specific words, it's different ways to say "where is" in French.

Anyway, what would be the best way to replace all those "`\w*\s`" in order to capture the words until the next punctuation mark? One more thing: the string that will be used by my code is fully cleaned by my parser, so there won't be any capital, dashes, apostrophes, or whatever, only lower case letters with spaces between them.

Comment: What about just `[\w\s]*`

Comment: Do you consider `_` a punctuation? If yes, `\w` can't be used as it matches `_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search for everything that is not a punctuation mark: `[^.!?,]*`

This gives you

```
words_to_find = r"(?<=ou est )[^.!?,]*|" \
    r"(?<=ou se trouve )[^.!?,]*|" \
    r"(?<=ou se situe )[^.!?,]*"
```

Comment: Same as above, it's working fine thanks :)

Comment: You might want to accept the answer from @Raphael

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is something like

```
(?<=ou est )[^,.!?\n]+
```

Here `[^,.!?\n]` stands for all punctations not allowed in the words to catch. You catch all until the first occurrence of one of these characters.
You can test it with regex101: https://regex101.com/r/PCeySp/1/

another approach could be

```
(?<=ou est )(\s*\w+)+
```

Here you catch `\s*\w+` any number of times. https://regex101.com/r/0lO4u7/1